# How to re-start activity after animation?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-animation

I am troubled with my splash-screen.
I am rotating an image in `imageview` and I want to start new activity after some time but it does not work. I tried following-

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
           ImageView ImageForRotation = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageForRotation);

            var loadedImage = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.SplashScreenImageRotation);

            ImageForRotation.StartAnimation(loadedImage);

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            StartActivity(LoginScreen);
         }
```

In an `xml file`  `android:repeatCount=3`
What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    startActivity(this,DestinationActivity.class);
```